# Count based on column and row

Tags: arrays, excel, countif

I can't seem to find something quite like this problem...
I have an array table where each row contains a random assortment of numbers 1-N

On another sheet, I have a table with column and row headers numbered 1-N

I want to count how many **rows** in the array contain both the column and row headers for *a given cell in the table.* Since countifs only reference the current cell in the specified array, they don't seem to be working in this scenario.

Example array:

```
A B C D
1 3 5 7
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8
...
```

Table results (symmetrical about the diagonal):

```
A B C D E F
. 1 2 3 4 5 ...
1 - 1 2 1 1
2 1 - 2 2 1
3 2 2 - 2 2
4 1 2 2 - 1
5 1 1 2 1 -
```

Would using nested countifs work?

Comment: A sample data set and expected results would help...

Comment: Data set added with expected results table.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand the logic.  Please explain in words (don't worry about the formula) _why_ the expected results are what they are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't agree with your results corresponding to 4/2, which surely should be 3, not 2, but this formula, based on the array table being in Sheet1 A1:D4 and the results table being in Sheet2 A1:F6, placed in cell B2 of the latter, should work:

`=IF($A2=B$1,"-",SUMPRODUCT(N(MMULT(N(COUNTIF(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1,ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$D$4)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$D$4)),),CHOOSE({1,2},B$1,$A2))>0),{1;1})=2)))`

Copy across and down as required.

*Note:* If your actual table is in fact much larger than that given, it will probably be worth adding a simple clause into the above to the effect that the results for approximately half of the cells are obtained from their symmetrical counterparts, rather than via calculation of this construction, thus saving resource.

Regards